# Can MikTeX and TeXLive share a common package installation tree?

Tags: miktex, texlive, tds

I am wondering whether it would be possible to use MikTeX and TeXLive reference the same TDS tree?

1. Then I could use both whenever I like without wasting space and worrying whether both has the same installed packages.
2. In actual fact I think it would be then possible to use a common tree on my XEN Dom0 and share it with all the installed DomUs.
3. I can then also do maintenance once from each of MikTeX and TeXLive
   and all the guests will reference the same TDS.

Maybe I'm just dreaming.

Comment: Short question: Why do you want to maintain two distributions?

Comment: Linux only doesn't have MikTeX any longer.

Comment: As a Linux user I never used MikTeX

Comment: MiKTeX never was for Linux. Maybe for MiKTeX 3.0?

Comment: I used MikTeX only on Windows, but my Windows' are now mere virtual guests on the host.  I will still for a long time to come, use these guests and I have documents and styles I build on them.  I can't just switch it off.  (There was a MikTeX for Linux, but it was discontinued and it was only pdftex.)

Comment: ?? I've been using MiKTeX for nearly 20 years, and  I only saw a `Package Manager` for Linux, never a distribution. However, I can't exclude some people compiled the sources of MiKTeX.

Comment: Similar as Bernard wrote: I am on the other hand a Linux user for nearly 18 years now and I never saw MikTeX on Linux.

Comment: There is no problem to use e.g. the main texmf-dist of texlive with miktex: You can simply attach it as a new root. Its packages will then in most case be found first. But I wouldn't merge the two main texmf trees: There are slight differences (e.g. in the placing of the binaries and the scripts) and managing the same tree with two update managers could get complicated. Space is cheep today.

Comment: See: [Building MiKTeX (GNU/Linux)](http://miktex.org/howto/build-unx) miktex-pdftex: MiKTeX implementation of the pdfTeX engine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will look into it, although space is maybe cheap, bandwith is not so cheap.  I like to the same things one of.  I recently copied a few 180GB images  and that took forever and a day, so reduction of duplication would be a bonus.

Comment: Updates aren't so much stress on bandwidth. But if you really want it I would suggest to install a full texlive and a basic miktex. You can then attach the texmf-dist as a root to miktex and keep it up-to-date. This should take care of most packages. You should check regularly with the miktex update manager if some miktex specific package has changed. You probably will have to install some more miktex packages (all the things that involves scripts and binaries like e.g. makeglossaries). Make sure that the `path` variable points only to one texsystem at one time.

Comment: It seems that I will have to move over to `TeXLive` as the `LuaLaTeX` in `MikTeX` has not been updated in the last few months and **0.76** is causing _warnings now_.  So the issue is now: "Overcome be events (OBE)".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I suggest that you reword and compile your comments as an answer so we can conclude this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem to use e.g. the main `texmf-dist` of TexLive with MikTeX: You can simply attach it as a new root. Its packages will then in most case be found first. But I wouldn't merge the two main texmf trees: There are slight differences (e.g. in the placing of the binaries and the scripts) and managing the same tree with two update managers could get complicated.

But if you really want it I would suggest to install a full TexLive and a basic MikTeX. You can then attach the `texmf-dist` as a root to MikTeX and keep it up-to-date. This should take care of most packages. You should check regularly with the MikTeX update manager if some MikTeX specific package has changed. You probably will have to install some more MikTeX packages (all the things that involves scripts and binaries like e.g. makeglossaries). Make sure that the `path` variable points only to the binary folder of one texsystem at one time.